# Passing parameters through a db.transaction function

Tags: javascript, sql

I think this is quite a noob question, but can't find a direct solution for it. This is my case:

```
var db = window.openDatabase("database.db", "1.0", "Any_Name", 20000);
db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);

//-------------------------------------

function queryDB (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM my_table', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
}
```

This runs with no problem, but when I try to send extra parameters through the queryDB function I always get an error, I have tried:

```
db.transaction(queryDB ("hello"), errorCB);
db.transaction(queryDB (db, "hello"), errorCB);
db.transaction(queryDB (tx, "hello"), errorCB);
```

and

```
function queryDB (tx, param1) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM my_table', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }
```

I am not sure from where is the queryDB function getting the **tx** values initially.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function queryDBWithParam(param1) {
  return function(tx) {
      //you can use parameter param1
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM my_table', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
  }
}

db.transaction(queryDBWithParam("hello"), errorCB);
```

Comment: Thank you! it works, I would never guess it by my own.